# Getting absolute URL from href

Tags: powershell, hyperlink, href

I'm trying to automate downloading files from a website, but links are relative. How do I get full path to the file?

```
$a = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://www.website.com/folder/default.aspx' -UseBasicParsing
```

$a.Links[$i].href - can be a relative path, so how can I expand it to a full path?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class and its [new(baseUri, relativeURLString)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.trycreate(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor:

```
function Get-AbsoluteURL($pageUrl, $url) {
    [Uri]::new([Uri]$pageUrl, $url).AbsoluteUri
}
```

Example:

```
Get-AbsoluteURL 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38899802/getting-blabla' `
                '../aa.jpg'
```

> ```
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/aa.jpg
> ```